# C include file in VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a simple C program using VS code; there are 3 files in my program.

"main.c",   "test.c",    "test.h"

the "main.c" file is located in the workspace directory and "test.h" file is in the header folder and this folder is located in the workspace directory. I want to include "test.h" in "main.c" file but I get the following error:

"fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory".

I have searched a lot and try many solutions but I could not solve this problem. I will appreciate any kind of help.

this is "c_cpp_properties.json" file:

```
{
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\header"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }],
    "version": 4
}
```

this is "task.json" file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\source\\test.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the include path for your compiler (note that this is compiler specific, VSCode does not include a build system). e.g.: for GCC you have to use the `-I` option (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html for the official docs)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your solution and the problem was solved. ‌But could you please explain to me what is "includePath" property in "c_cpp_properties.json" file?

Comment: That is purely for VSCode to provide code completion. It does not pass that information on to a compiler (since there is nothing built into the C/C++ Extension to do so)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments...

Comment: @MSGH can you provide your fixed solution in the context of your posted question so others can see how you did it?